# Convert Boolean Search Query To ElasticSearch Format

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm looking to take a 'regular' search query, like "(yes AND no) OR (maybe)" and convert it to elastic search format. AFAIK ES is based on Lucene, which does accept a similar query, so how come isn't there an easy way to query ES similarly? I didn't find a php lib that does this, which makes me wonder if I'm missing something. Are the two formats not easily convertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use verbatim Lucene queries in a [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "this AND that OR thus"    <--- put your Lucene query here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that. Why is it they have their own "must", "should" etc.. ? Is that a more powerful query language?

Comment: it's a more high-level query language with more flexibility than what Lucene offers.

Comment: Can I not use "fields" in your query to specify the return fields I require?

Comment: Sure you can, simply add `"_source": ["field1", "field2", ...]` above `"query"`

Comment: And if I want something like having another condition? for example I have a user_id in that index, and I'd like to add a user_id IN (1, 2, 3, ...)

Comment: I suggest you create a new question since that's a different issue ;-)

Comment: What about a multi word phrase? "this that AND thus" as far as I see by default it does OR between those. In order to force phrase I need to do +this +that? Any other way?

Comment: You can surround the terms with double quotes, as in `"this that" AND thus` but `this` and `that` won't be analyzed. If you want to also match the ordering, it's more complex and the `query_string` might not be the way to go.

Comment: But it's already surrounded with double quotes and single quotes don't seem to work.

Comment: You need to escape the double quote `"\"this that\" AND thus"`

Comment: I'm trying instead to use auto_generate_phrase_queries=true, but still the query `"query": "pull bear OR abcdefghijklmn"` doesn't bring the same results as `"query": "\"pull bear\" OR abcdefghijklmn"`. Am I misunderstanding the parameter? (the first also matches a mention of just pull, without bear right after it or even anywhere in the text, even if I change default_operator to AND)

Comment: Let's start another question with this new issue